# How can you access Chef LWRP attributes in a recipe

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, lwrp

With some of the default chef resources, it is possible to access some of their attributes after they have been called

```
# recipes/default.rb
f = file "/tmp/file_resource" do
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode "0755"
  action :create
end

log "Path to my file is #{f.path}" # outputs "/tmp/file_resource"
```

How can this be achieved in a custom LWRP (here is an example)

```
# resources/default.rb
actions :create
default_action :create

attribute :relative_path, :kind_of => String, :name_attribute => true
attribute :full_path, :kind_of => String
```

In this provider, I am trying to update the property of `new_resource.full_path` to be equal to the path of the file resource

```
# providers/default.rb
action :create do

  f = file "/path/to/my/resource/#{new_resource.relative_path}" do
    owner "root"
    group "root"
    mode "0755"
    action :create
  end

  new_resource.full_path(f.path)
  new_resource.updated_by_last_action(f.updated_by_last_action?)
end
```

However when I try to access `resource.full_path` in the recipe, it is `nil` rather than the expected `/path/to/my/resource/relative/path`

```
# recipes/default.rb
resource = my_awesome_lwrp "relative/path" do
  action :create
end

log "Full path for my resource: #{resource.full_path}" # outputs "Full path for my resource:"
```

This example is rather contrived I know, the real world application/reason for this can be seen in the default resource/provider here https://github.com/peterjmit/chef-ssl-cert

Comment: Did you try this example to see if it would work? I'm pretty sure lightweight resources have this ability by default, same as any other resource.

Comment: Though I should point out that resource attributes aren't normally assigned using `=`, and that changes you make to the resource in the provider won't be available during recipie compile time.

Comment: @Ajedi32 the example doesn't work, perhaps the fact that "changes made to the resources in the provider won't be available during recipe compile time" is the core of the problem here.

Comment: Well, this is a lightweight provider, so maybe the DSL shown here *does* actually run at recipie compile time. I'm not completely certain. My guess though is that it doesn't.

Comment: What isn't working? There's some code, but no question, error, stacktrace, etc.

Comment: @sethvargo My expectation was to be able to set/update the property on a resource in a provider, and then access it in a recipe (the lack of ability to do that is demonstrated by `resource.full_path` being `nil` in the recipe -  I will update the question for clarity

Comment: I have updated the question, I have _an answer_ but im not 100% sure it is the right approach, I will add an answer shortly

Comment: Right... because the `:create` action hasn't yet be called at that time. So that code (`new_resource.full_path(...)`) hasn't been executed yet. If you wrap that in a `ruby_block`, you'll get the value back.