# How to write regression tests for custom Chef resources?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, cookbook, lwrp

Given the minimal example

```
# resources/novowel.rb
resource_name :novowel
property :name, String, name_property: true, regex: /\A[^aeiou]\z/
```

I would like to write the unit tests in `spec/unit/resources/novowel_spec.rb`

- Resource 'novowel' for name should accept 'k'
- Resource 'novowel' for name should accept '&'
- Resource 'novowel' for name should NOT accept 'a'
- Resource 'novowel' for name should NOT accept 'mm'

to ensure that the name property still works correctly even if the regex is changed for some reason.

I browsed several top notch Chef cookbooks but could not find references for such testing.

How can it be done? Feel free to provide more complex examples with explicitly subclassing `Chef::Resource` if that helps achieve the task.

**Update 1:** Could it be that Chef does NOT FAIL when a property does not fit the `regex`? Clearly this should not work:

```
link '/none' do
  owner  'r<oo=t'
  to     '/usr'
end
```

but `chef-apply` (12.13.37) does not complain about `r<oo=t` not matching `owner_valid_regex`. It simply converges as if `owner` would not have been provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We wrap the DSL inside a little Ruby in order to know the name of the resource's Ruby class:

```
# libraries/no_vowel_resource.rb
require 'chef/resource'

class Chef
  class Resource
    class NoVowel < Chef::Resource
      resource_name :novowel
      property :letter, String, name_property: true, regex: /\A[^aeiou]\z/
      property :author, String, regex: /\A[^aeiou]+\z/
    end
  end
end
```

and now we can use RSpec with

```
# spec/unit/libraries/no_vowel_resource_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

require_relative '../../../libraries/no_vowel_resource.rb'

describe Chef::Resource::NoVowel do
  before(:each) do
    @resource = described_class.new('k')
  end

  describe "property 'letter'" do
    it "should accept the letter 'k'" do
      @resource.letter = 'k'
      expect(@resource.letter).to eq('k')
    end

    it "should accept the character '&'" do
      @resource.letter = '&'
      expect(@resource.letter).to eq('&')
    end

    it "should NOT accept the vowel 'a'" do
      expect { @resource.letter = 'a' }.to raise_error(Chef::Exceptions::ValidationFailed)
    end

    it "should NOT accept the word 'mm'" do
      expect { @resource.letter = 'mm' }.to raise_error(Chef::Exceptions::ValidationFailed)
    end
  end

  describe "property 'author'" do
    it "should accept a String without vowels" do
      @resource.author = 'cdrngr'
      expect(@resource.author).to eq('cdrngr')
    end

    it "should NOT accept a String with vowels" do
      expect { @resource.author = 'coderanger' }.to raise_error(Chef::Exceptions::ValidationFailed)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This only works specifically with the name property (which, incidentally, shouldn't be called `:name`).

Comment: @coderanger I beg to differ. Sure you can spec any property like this. See extended example above.

Comment: @coderanger Could you please explain why it might be problematic to have a name property called `name`?

Comment: Ah, when defining a custom property `name`, then this definition from `Chef::Resource` gets overridden: `property :name, String, coerce: proc { |v| v.is_a?(Array) ? v.join(", ") : v.to_s }, desired_state: false`

Answer (score 2):

You would use ChefSpec and RSpec. I've got examples in all of my cookbooks (ex. https://github.com/poise/poise-python/tree/master/test/spec/resources) but I also use a bunch of custom helpers on top of plain ChefSpec so it might not be super helpful. Doing in-line recipe code blocks in the specs makes it waaaay easier. I've started extracting my helpers out for external use in https://github.com/poise/poise-spec but it's not finished. The current helpers are in my Halite gem, see the readme there for more info.

Comment: To answer your edit, property validation is only run when the property is accessed, not when it is set. There are _reasons_ for this 

Comment: What does "accessing a property" mean? Something like in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25043690/2216961)?

Comment: `owner` and `to` are resource properties. In provider code we have things like `new_resource.owner` to get the value of that property and do something with it. The validation code happens then. Because ChefSpec stubs out providers, that can leave things such that a property never gets accessed and so invalid values are allowed.

Comment: So I could test the regex via RSpec'ing the provider?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no simple answer here. Setting up a test harness via ChefSpec for this is somewhat more involved than will fit on StackOverflow.

Comment: Quite strange. In the Puppet world, testing input validation for a native type is a simple RSpec exercise...

Comment: The actual test part is easy, it's doing the broader harness. If you make a normal recipe with a bunch of test cases you can run it as per normal with `SoloRunner#converge`.

Comment: I think I tricked out how to do this. Would you mind reviewing my answer below?